# trying to split a template member function into header and cpp files

Tags: c++, templates

The following code gives me an error `"unable to match function definition to an existing declaration"`. Is my syntax correct?

CharPlayer.h

```
class CharacterPlayer
    {
    public:
    template <class cType>
        cType createCharacter(cType characterType);

    };
```

CharPlayer.cpp

```
template <class cType>
cType CharacterPlayer::createCharacter(cType characterType)
{
    return 3;
}
```

Main

```
CharacterPlayer *controllerPntr = new CharacterPlayer;
    controllerPntr->createCharacter(1);
```

Comment: Also, the function return type is `void` in the header but `cType` in the .cpp.

Comment: woops. that was mybad